# Outlook addin can't find \\localhost\C$ path

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to run an outlook addin (vsto) on a server where some users only can access their drive via \localhost\C$. From there I'd like to install an outlook add-in, however it maps the path wrong:

> From: file:///C$/Users/user/Desktop/outlookaddin/addin.vsto
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException:
> Downloading file:///C$/Users/user/Desktop/outlookaddin/addin.vsto did not succeed.
>
> ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of the path  'C:\C$\Users\user\Desktop\outlookaddin\addin.vsto'.
>
> ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of the path   'C:\C$\Users\user\Desktop\outlookaddin\addin.vsto'.
>
> ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\C$\Users\user\Desktop\outlookaddin\addin.vsto'.

`C:\C$\Users\` obviously doesn't exist. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: How are you deploying? ClickOnce, msi or something else? You need to modify the bit that set the path in the registry (root\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\[your addin name])

Comment: Yes, with clickonce. I saw about the registry entry thing, but this will need to be done for thousands of users. Is it really the only option to change a registry entry on every single users pc?

Comment: What 'Publish Location' and 'Installation URL' on the Publish tab are you using?